# Ensuring if ConcurrentQueue enqueues an object or not

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, wcf

I am using a C# `ConcurrentQueue` in VS2010.  The `ConcurrentQueue` variable is static and the objects are queued from different threads.  In one other continuously running thread I'm de-queuing this object & storing in database.  Just after enqueuing the object, it is also sent to a wcf service.  Lately, we have discovered that few objects are sent & logged by the wcf service but it is not logged where it is being dequeued.

**Question**:
Is it possible that the object is not enqueued? How to ensure if the object is queued or not?

Note: There is no exception logged while dequeuing object.  The new objects are received & queued at around 1000/min.

Comment: Enqueue should always work, but it might have to wait for a lock, perhaps it is just blocked? Without seeing your code queuing items or sending the WCF request, I can't offer any suggestions.

Comment: Can't paste the code here.  Is it possible that the object is dropped if the lock is not available?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about any events available along with `ConcurrentQueue`. Alternately, I propose you to create a class and Wrap your `ConcurrentQueue` and then expose methods to `Enqueue & Dequeue` ( which actually Enqueue & Dequeue items from your `ConcurrentQueue` object). And then create two events ( two custom events that also need to be part pf your wrapper object), which can be triggered within your Enqueue & Dequeue methods, which will call your service method as and when threads perform Enqueue or Dequeue operation.